# Virtual Directories by host name

Tags: iis-7.5

Is is possible to create a virtual directory that is only for a particular host name. For example, I have an IIS site which responds to www.abc.com and www.xyz.com.  I'd like to create a virtual directory that only applies to xyz.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes & no.  With IIS you would be required to setup 2 sites (with the hostnames listed in the site bindings), one of which has the virtual directory, and the other without.

If you're not making use of the site bindings with hostnames, you're going to run into problems.  It's good practice to use them anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I can't set up two IIS sites as this causes conflicts with my wcms. My apologies for not mentioning this above.